# How to move a vhdx file?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

On my host, I'm running Hyper-V (Windows Server 2022 Core in Hyper-V role).

My host has a C: and a D: drive.  I've got one VM, which is running Windows Server 2022.  My VM has 2 vhdx files, one for its C: and one for its D:, and both drives are BitLockered and on the host's C: drive.

All I want to do is move the vhdx for my VM's D: drive from the host's C: to D:, using PowerShell.

I thought I'd need to do something like Remove-VMHardDiskDrive and then Add-VMHardDiskDrive, but Remove-VMHardDiskDrive doesn't take a path to my ddrive.vhdx file, and I'm not sure what I have to do regarding BitLocker.

I'm no admin.  Please walk me through the commands I need to use.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks for reformatting.  Much better!

Answer (score 3):

I paid someone to help, but I'll share the solution for others...

Here's how things had been configured for the VM:

```
Get-VMHardDiskDrive VM1

VMName ControllerType ControllerNumber ControllerLocation DiskNumber Path
------ -------------- ---------------- ------------------ ---------- ----
VM1 SCSI 0 0 C:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Disks\Cdrive.vhdx
VM1 SCSI 0 1 C:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Drives\Ddrive.vhdx
```

With the VM shut down, I moved the vhdx file for its D drive from the host's C to D:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Drives.  There were no snapshots to deal with.  Here's the command that changed the VM to use the moved vhdx file:

```
Get-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName VM1 -ControllerType SCSI -ControllerNumber 0 -ControllerLocation 1 | Set-VMHardDiskDrive -Path "D:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Drives\Ddrive.vhdx"
```

The first part retrieved the drive to change, then piped it into Set-VMHardDiskDrive to change its path.  Here's the result:

```
Get-VMHardDiskDrive VM1

VMName ControllerType ControllerNumber ControllerLocation DiskNumber Path
------ -------------- ---------------- ------------------ ---------- ----
VM1 SCSI 0 0 C:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Disks\Cdrive.vhdx
VM1 SCSI 0 1 D:\VMs\VM1\Virtual Hard Drives\Ddrive.vhdx
```

I then started the VM, and all was well.  The fact that the drive was BitLockered didn't come into play, because the file stayed on the same server, using its same virtual TPM. Voilà.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To change the path for a virtual disk:

- Start Hyper-V management
- Right-click the VM and select Settings
- Open SCSI Controller > Hard Drive
- Click on the disk
- Enter the new path of the VHDX.

You need to copy the file to the new location, then change the path as above.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking how to do this via PowerShell.

Comment: Why PowerShell?